# Iterating through 2 lists and checking for values

Tags: python, list

I wish to see whether values x exists in values y of a list, if they do, I want to print out the total number of such values.

```
z=0
for x,y in zip(labels,n):
    if x in y:
        z=z+1
print(z)
```

This is what *labels* looks like:

```
[['20011', '20048'],
 ['20011', '20048'],
 ['20011', '20048'],
 ['20011', '20048']]
```

And this is what *n* looks like:

```
['20011', '20048' ,'20011', '20048']
```

I get a zero on printing out z. What am I doing wrong? If I don't define z, I get an error saying no z defined.

Comment: Did you mean `if y in x:`?

Comment: Do you mean to find wheter the lists in `labels` are contained in `n`?

Comment: No, the other way round.. whether the values in n are contained in labels by iterating row wise.

Comment: @jdkc: But then I receive an error that says: 
*TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not numpy.ndarray*

Comment: @CoderQueen Check my answer, it converts your list into `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html#numpy.intersect1d) enables to get the intersection between 2 arrays, then you can use size to get the count of unique elements in both arrays :

```
import numpy as np
labels = np.array([[20011,20048],[20011,20048],[20011,20048],[20011,20048]])
n = np.array([20011,20048,20011,20048])
z = np.intersect1d(n,labels).size
print z # counts 2
```

[`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) enables to check if each elements of an 1D array are in a 2nd array, then you convert into list and count the True item (not unique elements) :

```
z = np.in1d(n,labels).tolist().count(True)
print z # counts 4
```

Comment: This gives me a 0. Is it because labels is a list of list while n is just a list?

Comment: I get 2 with your example

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly. I had some issue in my code. My bad. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you've numpy.in1d too. It provides an array to check if each element of n is in labels. In this case, you'll count 4.

Comment: Why does the difference exist in the z values then? One gives 2 and the other 4? Which one is the right case?

Comment: It depends on your need. With intersect1d you'll get the number of unique elements that are in both n and labels. With in1d the number of elements n that are in labels.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the count if the elements appear anywhere, get the union of all the sublists and see how many times each element from l2 appears in it:

```
l = [['20011', '20048'],
 ['20011', '20048'],
 ['20011', '20048'],
 ['20011', '20048']]


l2 = ['20011', '20048' ,'20011', '20048']
union = set.union(*map(set,l))
print(sum(ele in union for ele in l2)) # ->  4
```

If you don't want to count unique elements more than once, get the intersection:

```
l = [['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048']]

l2 = ['20011', '20048', '20011', '20048']
inter = set.union(*map(set, l)).intersection(l2)

print(len(inter)) # ->  2
```

If you want to use the elements from the sublists for the count:

```
l = [['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048']]

l2 = ['20011', '20048', '20011', '20048']
st = set(l2)
from itertools import chain
print(sum(ele in st for ele in chain.from_iterable(l)))
```

To count based on the sublist being disjoint or not from `n`, you can use `set.isdisjoint` so if there is any common elements `not st.isdisjoint(sub)` will be True.:

```
l = [['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048'],
     ['20011', '20048']]

l2 = ['20011', '20048', '20011', '20048']
st = set(l2)
print(sum(not st.isdisjoint(sub) for sub in l)) # -> 4
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a lot!